# Print nested array associative array php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I am looping through an **array**, and I want to print some of the **keys** and **values** of the array.

I can print the first array that is index 0 but I can not print  sub array.

```
  @foreach($data[0] as $k => $v)
  {{$v['bill_no']}}  //prints b-0002
   @foreach($v['customer_details'] as $kk => $vv)
    Customer Name : {{$vv['name']}} //gives the error
   @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

This is my array:

```
    Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( [id] => 14 [customer_id] => 2 [referral_id] => 1 [sq_id] => 
    [bill_no] => b0002 [bill_date] => 07-09/2018 [payment_mode] => cash 
    [delivered_by] => tsr [net_total] => 15000
    [customer_details] => Array ( [id] => 2 [code] =>
    csdc [name] => jhon k [address] => mangalore [telephone] => cs [mobile] 
    => sd [tin] => sdc [gstin] => dsc
    [opening_balance] => 10000 [remarks] => sd [credit_limit] => 100 
    [bank_name] => HDFC [account_no] =>
    0022 [ifsc] => 5588 [account_name] => jhon [created_at] => 2018-08-13 
    22:04:10 [updated_at] => 2018-12-24
    09:39:00 ) [sold_items] =>
```

I want to print the name of the customer

```
Name: {{$vv['name']}}
```

Comment: try `$v['customer_details']['name']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
@foreach($data[0] as $k => $v)
  {{$v['bill_no']}}  //prints b-0002
   @foreach($v['customer_details'] as $vv)    // As it is associative array, we are not going to use `$kk`
    Customer Name : {{$vv['name']}} //Now this should work.
   @endforeach
 @endforeach
```